# Allocating file of given size in python, then fill it with data

Tags: python, file

I have a software writing out large files of a known size. Multiple instances of the software will run in parallel. I want to avoid running out of storage. Since each instance knows how much data it will produce, this should be possible. However if I just open and write to the files in the usual way, they will grow larger incrementally, whereas I want to allocate the full size at the beginning and then fill the files from the beginning.

Will one of the following work?:

- Create a file of all zeros with the given size. Then open it again and write to it.
- Create a file of all zeros with the given size. Then seek to the beginning and write from there.

Comment: What advantage is gained by creating one large file at once _vs_ creating the file of same size incrementally?

Comment: Are you looking for contiguous files?  The exact behaviour will depend on the file system in use, but generally that's not possible without a very low-level interface.

Comment: Beware of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Comment: the advantage is the following. Say I have one instance running, there is not much space left and I start another. If the first instance did not allocate all the memory it needs, but does it incrementally the second instance can not know whether there is enough space left for it

Comment: I already saw sparse files mentioned. From what I understand they won't work for my problem